# I have been installing perl module ex::lib::zip but getting faild at the test part

Tags: perl

Installation of ex::lib::zip failed. Check the output above and try installing manually.
You can also install the module from CPAN with the command perl -MCPAN -e shell.

Making, testing and installing ex::lib::zip ..

---

Compiling module

---

```
Executing /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL  && make ..
                                                                                                    
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Have /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
Want /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.34
Your perl and your Config.pm seem to have different ideas about the
architecture they are running on.
Perl thinks: [perl-base]
Config says: [x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi]
This may or may not cause problems. Please check your installation of perl
if you have problems building this extension.
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for ex::lib::zip
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
cp zip.pm blib/lib/ex/lib/zip.pm
Running Mkbootstrap for zip ()
chmod 644 "zip.bs"
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- zip.bs blib/arch/auto/ex/lib/zip/zip.bs 
644
"/usr/bin/perl" "/usr/local/share/perl/5.34.0/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap '/usr/share/perl/5.34/ExtUt
ils/typemap' -typemap '/tmp/.webmin/ex-lib-zip-0.04/typemap'  zip.xs > zip.xsc
mv zip.xsc zip.c
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/
usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2 -g   -DVERSION=\"0.04\" -DXS_VERSIO
N=\"0.04\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.34/CORE"   zip.c
rm -f blib/arch/auto/ex/lib/zip/zip.so
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc  -shared -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector-strong  zip.o  -o blib/arch/auto/ex
/lib/zip/zip.so  \
      \
  
chmod 755 blib/arch/auto/ex/lib/zip/zip.so
Manifying 1 pod document
```

---

Testing module

```
Executing make test ..
                                                                                                    
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- zip.bs blib/arch/auto/ex/lib/zip/zip.bs 
644
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Har
ness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00basic.t ........ ok
t/01stored.t ....... ok
PerlIO::gzip can't yet clone active layers at /usr/share/perl/5.34/SelfLoader.pm line 102.
t/02data_handle.t .. 
Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 5/6 subtests 
t/03autoloader.t ... ok
t/04comment.t ...... ok
t/pushmepullyou.t .. ok

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/02data_handle.t (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 1 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 6 tests but ran 1.
Files=6, Tests=23,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.04 usr  0.02 sys +  0.17 cusr  0.01 csys =  0.24 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/6 test programs. 0/23 subtests failed.
make: *** [Makefile:1025: test_dynamic] Error 255
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `perl -V` and the show the command you used to install the module?

Answer (score 1):

From the output:

```
Your perl and your Config.pm seem to have different ideas about the
architecture they are running on.
Perl thinks: [perl-base]
Config says: [x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi]
This may or may not cause problems. Please check your installation of perl
if you have problems building this extension.
```

This typically happens when you have two different perl installation interacting in ways they shouldn't. For example, you have some PERL* environment variables set that point one perl to the installation of a different perl.